# python interval arithmetic library

Tags: python

I would like to know if there exists a python interval arithmetic library with the following features:

If x and y are both intervals, eg: [1.2,2.1], [3.8,9.9], then their sum/product/ratio is an interval, and in particular, any real number in the first interval plus/times/over the a real number in the second interval, will be contained in the resulting interval.

In particular, I would like to know of such a library that does this and accounts for floating point error so that the results can be used in mathematical proofs. I have found some libraries such as this one: https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/ that account for error on real numbers, however they don't do so in this stricter sense that I require.

Thanks to TimPeters for suggesting this library:
https://mpmath.org/doc/current/contexts.html#arbitrary-precision-interval-arithmetic-iv

I think this should be the correct tool to use.

Comment: By what definition to you mean interval?

Comment: Have you seen the builtin [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) libraries? `decimal` deals with floating/fixed point arithmetic.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama, I mean a pair of extended reals (Reals union ±∞), a lower bound and an upper bound

Comment: @Jab, I don't think either of these libraries will work for me as I need rigorous assurance that the result of my computation will contain the 'true' answer. For example, I don't want small floating points errors to result in the true answer being outside the resulting interval.

Comment: Suggest looking into the widely used `mpmath` extension. It has full support for basic arithmetic on intervals, but spotty support across its many "advanced" math function. `mpmath` does binary floating-point, but with usable-settable precision. https://mpmath.org/doc/current/contexts.html#arbitrary-precision-interval-arithmetic-iv

Comment: @TimPeters, Thanks, this looks like what I want. In particular this line sound encouraging: "the basic guarantee of interval arithmetic is that ()⊆fhat () for any input interval "

However, they include this note: "

Note

The support for interval arithmetic in mpmath is still experimental, and many functions do not yet properly support intervals. Please use this feature with caution. "

I only need to compute products, sums, differences and ratios, so assuming these functions are covered, I am happy with this library.

Comment: @TimPeters, I'll accept this as an answer if you're willing to address my concerns around the library being 'experimental' as stated in the docs you linked to. Thanks again

Comment: I gave this as a comment instead of as answer because I've never actually used `mpmath`'s intervals. So I can't credibly address your concerns. I've happily used `mpmath` for many other things, though, and in my experience it's absolutely a first-rate library.

Comment: I see, thanks for being honest about your lack of experience with this part of the library. I'll let someone who does have experience with it vouch for it then. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: To account for the arithmetic proof / floating point errors, you could use a tensor, however I am not sure which library would work best for that.

Comment: In the absence of definitive answers, I encourage you to download `mpmath` and just try it. For basic arithmetic, it's really not hard to write rigorously correct interval algorithms, especially not when - as in `mpmath` - the arithmetic is implemented in software, with total control over intermediate precision and rounding. The library has solid implementations of many things much harder to do. As part of its _basic_ functionality, it already had to implement "round to +inf" and "round to -inf" rounding, and those are the heart of what interval arithmetic needs to build on.

Comment: Thanks @TimPeters, I did download and use it and it works great. As for my particular use case, I'm happy with it, however as for an answer to this question, I'm not sure where to go from here. At this point I'd be happy to accept any answer that suggests using mpmath, however if that doesn't happen, I might just close the question. Let me know what you suggest I do.

Comment: Cool! I thought you'd be happy :-) To put this behind you, I added this suggestion as "an answer" just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in comments, the OP appeared to be happy with the basic interval arithmetic facilities (binary floating point, with user-settable precision, emulated in software) supplied by the widely used [`mpmath` extension library](https://mpmath.org/).

Comment: One thing that isn't ideal about mpmath's intervals is that they support only *closed* intervals. The [portion library](https://pypi.org/project/portion/) supports open, closed and half open intervals, but does not seem to implement arithmetic operations.